# Response.Redirect not working in AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am getting alert box with the following when I am using Response.Redirect but I need I need it in server side code to change the page after all the conditions are successful.

How can I come out of this issue?

error:

> sys.webforms.pagerequestmanagerparseerrorexception: The message
>   received from the server could not be parsed. Common casuse s for this
>   error are when the response is modified by calls to response.write(),
>   response filters, httpmodules, or server trace is enabled. details:
>   Error parsing near

```
<!DocType html PUB'.
```

Comment: Could you provide your page aspx markup and the code you're calling from the ajax request, so we could do a better job in helping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using an UpdatePanel, add the following `ScriptModule` to your web.config:

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</httpModules>
```

Your other option is to register the control doing the redirect as a postback control. With an UpdatePanel you can do this by adding a `PostBackTrigger`. You can also use the script manager:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(Button1);
```

Comment: James can you answer this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839401/ajax-not-working-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

When you send AJAX request, you need to receive AJAX response where will be the URL for redirecting. Then use javascript for redirecting: Location.href = .

Like this example:

```
        $.post(
            "http://dummysite.com/Request",
            parameters,
            function (response) {
                location.href = response.returnedUrl;
            },
            'json');
```

Comment: I couldn't understand can you please be bit more clear. What should I write for `Current_Page's` `Button_Click` and as you said AJAX should receive my response. What should I write at `Destination_Page's` `Page_Load` ?

Comment: Looks like he is not using JQuery AJAX but in general you're right.

Comment: @MartijnB - Yes! I need a simple server side ASP.NET code to redirect.

Comment: @KarsM I want to help you but you will need to provide more information. See my comment in your question. A Response.Redirect initiated from a AJAX request will not redirect the user to the new page. One solution is the one provided by Sergey. If you update your question with your situation I can provide a solution which fits your bill beter.