# AJAX not working in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, ajax.net

I have .NET 4.0 and .NET 2.0 installed in my computer I tried running a AJAX.NET application with Asynchronous Triggered Timer Tick function and my page is reloading i.e. (Asynchronouspostback is not working). I tried changing my App Pool to `Classic .NET 4.0` and I am getting error

```
HTTP Error 404.2 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the ISAPI and CGI Restriction list settings on the Web server.
```

And when I change my App Pool to `Classic .NET 2.0` page is being displayed but being postback'd upon timer intervals.

Is there anything more I should add to my Web.Config file

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <pages enableEventValidation="false" enableViewState="false" enableViewStateMac="false">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32768" executionTimeout="3600"/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </httpModules>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

and my AJAX.NET code is

```
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="200" ontick="Timer1_Tick" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the isapi and cgi restrictions problem by opening IIS Manager, select the server, and double-clicking on the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions icon (assuming win 7 or win server 2008).

In the resulting screen, right click on each entry for ASP.NET v2.0.50727 (assuming a 64-bit OS; will only be one in 32-bit), select `Edit...` and check the `Allow extension path to execute` checkbox.

This should allow ASP.Net 2.0 apps to run.

As far as the page posting back, the best suggestion is to wrap it in a separate update panel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false"
    ID="upTimer">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="2000" ontick="Timer1_Tick" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

You may also want to consider increasing the timer interval from 200 milliseconds unless you absolutely need it that often (I have modified it above to be 2 seconds).

There is also one other setting to check: if you migrated this app from a .Net 1.1 application, you may have the `<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" />` tag left over in your web.config.

If this is the case, this will absolutely cause this problem, [as reported by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/10/gotcha-don-t-use-xhtmlconformance-mode-legacy-with-asp-net-ajax.aspx) of Microsoft fame.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sorry its incomplete! I have major issue with AJAX.NET Timer Tick issue. Still page is reloading for every 2 seconds even after doing this.

Comment: Not sure why that is (will look a little more), but you might want to consider changing your Timer interval. Right now, it is set for 200 milliseconds, which could be causing page confusion.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a possible solution for the postback problem.

Comment: Whatever its changed to. Page shouldn't reload right? I used the same property in VS10 and executed hundreds of applications in cassini server and everything worked with without any kind of issues but when I run the same code in IIS I am getting all these issues.

Comment: Also found one more, very likely cause of the problem. Answer updated again.

Comment: Update with your another answer please!

Comment: Did you try wrapping the timer in a separate update panel and checking for the xhtmlconformance tag? If neither of these worked, then there must be something else involved.

Comment: `<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" />` is present in my web.config file what should I do with that?

Comment: Ah, that's the cause of the problem: remove it. See the link I included in the answer for more details.

Comment: Awesome! it worked like a charm when I removed it! Thanks a lot for your valuable assistance :)